# Why all my objects turned white?

Tags: texturing, edit-mode

[image]I worked yesterday on my project and all was fine. The problem started today when I opened the file.

Comment: can you share a screenshot or the blender file to check what's going on?

Comment: Try switching to a different shading mode an back. Then double-check all the lights etc.